# How should I tip for food in a UK pub? At the bar, or at my table?

Tags: uk, food-and-drink, local-customs, tipping

I'm in a pub in England. I went up to the bar and asked for a plate of fish and chips (to be served to my table) and a pint (handed to me on the spot). My money was collected at the bar.

I would like to leave a tip (10 percent or so is customary, I understand). Should I leave it on the table when I go, or should I have given it to the bartender when I paid?

Answer (score 29):

Tipping is optional in general in the UK, rather than customary. Especially in a pub food environment, it's unexpected (much more common when the bill is brought to your table), although always of course welcomed. In general if you are tipping, it is done at approximately the same time as paying.

The normal way of tipping in a pub where money is exchanged at the bar would be to indicate to the barman to "keep the change" or "and one for yourself" – adding the cost of an extra drink to the bill.

If you feel that it won't be imagined that you simply forgot the money, and you aren't worried that other patrons (or passers by from the street) will steal it, then you could also leave money on the table. Note: I would not do this in any pub that sees high traffic – someone is very likely to just take it and buy a pint.

Comment: Thanks. So really I think the easiest thing would have been to add a tip when I paid. I resolved the issue by buying another pint, and tipping the bartender extra on this one (" keep the change"). He was also clearing tables so seemed to be the right person to get it :-)

Comment: Basically yes. Noone was going to complain if you just walked up to the bar and handed them some money mind, although they may have given you a funny look.

Comment: "Keep the change" is common; I've never in my 20-odd years of going to pubs heard anyone say "and one for yourself" or anything similar, despite having lived in several different cities around England. Also, the question specifically asks about food: offering them "and one [meal] for yourself" would be excessive unless your party contained at least eight or so people.

Comment: Just a small note that "and one for yourself" is also a popular "pulling" technique (flirting) and you may get a rather different reaction than what you intended

Comment: I've overheard other punters saying "and one for yourself" either 2 or 3 times ever. Most of those I don't think were attempts to flirt, although I am sure it is used for that. In general, if you're a foreginer who goes around saying that, you're going to look like a foreigner who read about it on the internet. But Americans insisting on tipping for everything is just Americans abroad anyway.

Comment: Myself and some other Brits were discussing the "and one for yourself" thing the other day. Roughly half (mostly younger, <25) had never even heard of it and thought it sounded weird. Of those who had (mostly >25), most agreed it was slightly old fashioned and something you'd expect in, for example, a quiet rural pub where the barman is also the landlord (therefore won't sack himself for drinking on the job!) and the tipper is a regular who considers the barman a friend. Never ever ever in a chain pub or a busy inner city pub.

Comment: I'd like to throw my 2pence worth in. I am British and have lived in the Midlands and Northwest of England all my life (I am also over 25)

I have on occasion told the barmaid in my local family pub to "have one for yourself" in the run up to Christmas time. This was most *definitely* not an attempt to flirt or pull the barmaid in question. 

I have also heard this on Christmas day to a landlord in a village pub.

Comment: I think the terminology for tipping bar staff is a regional thing. Around Manchester the common phrase is _and your own_ when handing over your money, and they will typically take a small tip, say 20p, out of your change.

Comment: @user568458: Meh, I'm 28 and I hear it (and do it) all the time. It just depends what pubs you're in. You probably won't get it in some shitty Wetherspoons on the high street, but in an _actual_ pub (not necessarily rural, but you probably wanna go a mile or two out of town) you will hear it constantly. .... which is pretty much what you said. Actually I think the bigger factor is whether you know the staff. It's less of a tipping strategy and more of a friendly thing to do on an afternoon/evening/night out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, that sounds about right. *Regulars* in a proper cornerstone-of-the-community *Pub*, yes. *Customers* in a *Bar*, no. And I guess if it seems old fashioned that's a sad indictment of the slow death of real (pub-based) community spirit...

Comment: @user568458: I agree. And I note that the question refers to pubs, although to be honest with the table service aspect I realise the OP may not have meant pub as we do.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I've worked as a barman in the North West (some time ago now!). "Have one for yourself" was very common. I've used it myself many times both North and South.

Answer (score 11):

I'm British, have lived in the South-East of England all my life and have been using pubs for 30 years all over the UK.

There are pubs and there are pubs. Many UK "pubs" are now basically restaurants in an old pub building. Hardly anyone sits at the bar and drinks. Your food - and the bill - are brought to your table. In these, normal restaurant rules apply, you can give a tip when paying the bill, you can leave some money on the table - or you can not tip at all and it won't be a problem. If you pay for food and drinks at the bar, it would look strange if you tipped.

You DO NOT tip at the bar for drinks. "Have one for yourself" is something I've heard twice in my life, once from someone who knew the barman well and was talking to him constantly - the other from someone who wanted to impress a pretty barmaid.

Comment: Does your final paragraph only apply to the places described in the second paragraph? Because it is completely incorrect for real pubs. If you've only heard that twice in your life, you have spent barely any time at all in actual pubs. You'd be more likely to hear it twice per _night_ in those. Then again, if you're a Southerner, that might explain it.. :P

Answer (score 8):

This is an experience answer, no links from me here.

As a regular visitor to the UK and going out with locals, I have seen both.
In a busy pub, most people do not leave money on the table as the staff can miss it being there.
But when the pub is quiet, like after the end of the lunch rush, it is quite common to see people leaving money on the table.

[image: table with some glasses and an empty crisp packet]
*Photo by Willeke*

When you pay for food or drinks, you can just add money to the bill and pay more or round it up and tell the staff that they can keep (part of) the change.

If you are just buying drinks, or pay for the drinks separate from paying for the dinner, you can again add to the money to be paid, but I have heard quite a few English people say: "and one for yourself" meaning that the bar man can take a drink on your cost but often they just add a drink to the bill but put the money into a tips piggy bank.

Comment: Are we supposed to be able to see money in that photo? I can't see it...

Comment: That is not a £5 note, it's a bag of crisps!

Comment: I want to go to this country where Lay's bags are valid currency.

Comment: @GayotFow Even thoguh it's obviously not a British pub, since Lay's is branded as Walker's, here?

Comment: I've never heard anyone saying "and one for yourself" or anything similar, in 20-odd years of pub-going, living in various cities in England. Also, the question asks specifically about food: a tip of "and one [meal] for yourself" would be excessive, especially given that tipping in the UK is usually aroudn the 10%/round-up-the-bill level.

Comment: AND the text on the crisps says "Nouvelle Recette + Des Goût". This is a table in a French pub with no money on it...

Comment: It is a 'pub' in Paris, and as you have to look for the details in text, I think it is a good enough match. And no money on this table, as we have not yet left it yet.

Comment: @DavidRicherby in the question the OP mentions paying for dinner and a pint, and in my answer I mention the 'one for yourself' being one drink or money equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: An *empty* bag of crisps. :-)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Then you haven't been paying attention, or you're only going to crappy chain "pubs" in city centres. :) Or maybe you stayed in the South too long...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, no and no, respectively.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Then something strange is definitely going on.

Comment: Just last night the guy who was served before me in the pub said "have one for yourself" to the barman. This was in a relatively small but not out of town pub.

Comment: @lightness Apparently it's a regional thing. As someone living in the north-west of the UK, I generally do the 'and yours mate' thing, and the barman takes 20p or so, so I was surprised to read David Richerby's comment. Then I found [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/the-filter/11271397/Never-ever-tip-a-pub-barman.html).

Comment: @peterG: *shrug* My friends in London (some customers, some bartenders) engage in this all the time.

Answer (score 8):

You don't tip in pubs; at least, not in the South around London. If you appreciate the barman/barmaid, offer to buy them a drink when you buy your round. This is a reminder that they are ordinary people like you who like a drink, and not just servants.

They may pour their drink on the spot, or they may choose not to and drink later; in that case, they will take the monetary amount of the drink of their choosing.

I wish I could remember where I learned this. It may have been written down or it may have been word of mouth. Nevertheless it has been very valuable.

Comment: Yes, a good explanation of the "one for yourself" rationale. You don't tip because everyone's equal in a pub, the proper pub being a refuge from hierarchy, rudeness and other pointless irritations.

Comment: One written down source would be *Watching the English* by Kate Fox.

Answer (score 7):

You'll often find (sometimes improvised) tip jars next to the cash register, or somewhere behind the counter. If you feel like tipping you can place your cash in there. For completeness sake look for something like this:

[image: pub tip jar] 
Image courtesy of blogspot.

Comment: Balancing a coin on a floating lemon is also a common thing seen in pubs, generally though, it isn't the norm to tip (though I'm sure it will be welcomed by the staff!)

Comment: Good advice in general, but I didn't see a tip jar in this particular pub.

Comment: Often in pubs I see the tip "jar" (often a pint glass) *behind* the bar, and the staff put money in it when told keep the change/for you/etc

Answer (score 6):

In this situation I would say that tipping would be considered odd/unusual.

You would usually tip the waiter/waitress in a restaurant or pub if you were paying at the table. I.e. they presented you with a bill at the end of your meal; the tip being in response to receiving what you considered to be good service.

If you were paying in advance for your meal at the bar then you don't know if you will receive good service or not.

However, if you *have* paid in advance you *could* hand a tip over after your meal to the barman/barmaid on your way out as a thank you.

In either case who actually ends up with this tip money varies a great deal from place to place: [Where does your tip really go? The truth about restaurant gratuities](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/11646497/tips-vs-service-charge-in-restaurants.html), which is one reason why people can be reluctant to tip at all in the UK (especially in pub/restaurant chains)

Note that tipping in the UK *is* optional unlike the USA where you are expected to tip 15-20% as the norm, regardless of whether you paid before or after your meal.

Comment: +1 Generally in the UK you only tip for table service, so in a pub where you order / pay at the bar I wouldn't expect a service charge.

Comment: @JamesYale - Agreed. There definitely would not be a service charge added to the bill for food drink ordered at the bar. The question is more about whether the customer should give a voluntary tip or not.

Comment: I'd consider a service charge vs a tip roughly analogous in the majority of cases.

Comment: It made me genuinely angry when I went to a restaurant / bar place in Shoreditch (I won't name it) and discovered, after ordering at the bar and then checking my receipt once I'd sat back down, that a 12.5% service charge had been added to my bill. For what!? They wanted about £3 to carry a single pizza from the kitchen to the table.

Comment: @Richiban was it a place that also serves as a takeaway? My local fish and chips place adds 10% if you eat in; the service referred to in that case is "providing you with a warm clean place to eat"

Answer (score 1):

We only ever eat out in pubs when we go on our Easter and summer hols, but this is what I always do:

If the food has been good, we've been looked after and I pay at the bar at the end, I'll say to the person behind the bar 'I never know what to do with tips in pubs, so could I buy you, the waitress and the chef a drink?' If I've paid for it when I ordered it I do the same when I buy a post meal pint.

It's always been greatly received and probably actually a bit of a stingy tip considering there's seven of us including two kids with various food allergies. We've occasionally used a place more than once during a holiday and have always been welcomed back and nothing dubious appears to have happened to the food, so I think my method does okay!

Answer (score 0):

My skinflint tipping strategy in pubs and restaurants is thus:

- If in a chain pub like 'Spoons or somewhere, where you pay when you order, I never leave a tip.
- See if the bill already includes an 'Optional' service charge. If so, I don't tip.
- Remove the price of all alcohol from the bill, then leave a  10%  tip on the remainder. I'm already paying over the odds for a bottle of wine, so why add another 10% to that?